# Distorted visual sound design

Tags: design

Ok judging by the title I am sure you are saying..."what???" If so, let me ask/explain.
I have recently been tasked to designing some audio for a visual piece that entails a corrupted video feed with dialogue. The only example I can think of right now is this:

In this clip, General Zod takes over the global television feed and speaks to the world. I know that there are design elements in this (layered sound effects and what not) but My question is, how to you go about designing the dialogue to distort and degrade in time with the visuals?

I have seen this done in countless other movies (all of which have slipped my mind right now) but if anyone out there knows this trick, could they please share it with me? Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 3):

"in time with the visuals" - but everything in sound post is done 'in time with the visuals'
I'm not sure I understand your question... You have a reference QT video with burnt in timecode, in a codec suitable for sound editing (ie NOT h264) and you scrub and/or crawl through the video, frame by frame if necessary, dropping markers & placing/editing sounds at the sync points... right?

In terms of generating elements there are tons of FSU & glitch plugins out there to generate potential material.. GRM Freeze, Effectrix, Glitch etc... I would try using GRM Freeze to grab a word just before the visual glitch point & then try various buffer glitch effects & print them to new audio (wild, ie not in sync to picture) Then select the printed bits you want and edit them into sync...

Comment: Oh snap!!! I didnt even think about GRM Freeze or Effectrix...MAN! Thank you that is what I was exactly what I was aiming for. So much going through the head couldn't think/see the solution. In essence, I basically want to take the dialogue and "Gitch it" to go with the visuals. I know that there is sound designing elements to add to this but really it was trying to think of a way to morph and twist the dialogue.

Comment: EUREKA!!!! Thank you much for just bring the obvious out!!!

Comment: Yeah I just looked these up and sadly out of all of them i would like to have, GRM is a bit much. So I am going with the other 2 to get what I need done. Thanks again for the info!!!

Answer (score 2):

It's all down to good editing, and a good palette of sounds. I go about this by placing markers on the timeline at key points, then edit to those. It does take a while, but the results are always very satisfying afterwards.

Comment: Also worth noting, you can set the grid to follow markers (& not linear time divisions). So if you mark up a complex scene with a lot of markers, you can use them as a non linear grid which is very useful when layering etc...

Comment: @timprebble That is such a very useful tip!

Answer (score 1):

Plugins by Red Giant called Trap Code - Sound Key would accomplish this effect. check some examples.

http://www.redgiant.com/products/all/trapcode-sound-keys/examples/#tabs

Comment: Yeah I know about this plugin. I am more looking for a technique centered toward the sound design aspect of of the visual. So really how to mangle the voice and glitch it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple old trick I use to distort the sounds as if it was digitally interfered is to take a very very small piece of the sound and duplicate a number of time (it depends of the length of the duplicated clip), each time there is a visual interference. In Man Of steel, it's really more complex, Tim is right, many Glith edited piece of sounds. 
But If you're in a hurry, my method is very fast and efficient. You can hear a the beginning of this commercial, what it does on 9/11 reporter voices.

http://www.caviarcontent.com/branded-content/65/reynald-gresset/fight

I MUST say that It is the Director's Cut, the original commercial have been sound designed by someone else (sorry I don't know who, if you recognize yourself I'd be glad to know), so this version is a blend of the original SD and what I added for the Director's Cut. But For the voice treatments we're talking about, it's me.